# How to parse an element in xml file using JAVA?

Tags: jaxb, docx4j

I have a word document (.docx extension). I am trying to modify it using 
its xml file. I am fetching the element using XPATH.

I am using XPATH = "//w:p[w:r[w:t[contains(text(),'"+SectionName+"')]]]";

It is able to find some section, But when I am searching a section which 
has property "Heading3new" the XPATH not able to find it, It is returning 0 index.

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00A34CB3" w:rsidRPr="000B42A9" w:rsidRDefault="00A34CB3" 
w:rsidP="00A34CB3">
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="Heading3new"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:bookmarkStart w:id="18" w:name="_Toc480554185"/>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="000B42A9">
<w:lastRenderedPageBreak/>
<w:t xml:space="preserve">Product Software</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:t>Modules</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="17"/>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="18"/>
</w:p>
```

In XPATH in place of SectionName I am passing "Product Software", But It returning 0 index, The same XPATH I used in the other word document, for that document It is working fine.

Is there any other way to parse the element which has property "Heading3" or "Heading3new" ?

Comment: Are you using docx4j?  If so,see comment at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/parts/XPathEnabled.java#L59 and other limitations/issues regarding XPath support in JAXB. As an alternative, see TraversalUtils

Comment: Yes, I am using docx4j. Can this issue will be resolve using different jar ? Now I am using docx4j.3.3.0.jar

Comment: Which JAXB are you using?